# Rewriting Push Notification Content in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a chat application, i want to rewrite Push Notification Content (alert) in iOS.

Suppose the alert came is: **+911234567890 : Hi how are you**

In this alert **+911234567890** is the contact number in my phone named **My Tester**, i just want to rewrite the push notification to: **My Tester : Hi how are you**

How it can be implemented

This needs to work if the app is not running also.

May sample code is below for process push:

```
(void)application:(UIApplication )application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary )userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:
(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Comment: This is possible inside app, i.e. if you are displaying notification list some where inside your application then there you can change this. But with push notification you don't have any control over the text which is displayed. What is pushed from backend will be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In push notification you can display those content that is **received by the push notification**. If you want display name with push notification then you have to **send it from server**.Even you can show in **Whats App**, **Whats App** notification doesn't show actual name we have store in phone book.It **only show the name which is send by the server**

Comment: ya, we are currently using name from server, but client ask the requirement to show name from his contact list.

Comment: Then you have to store contact name in your server.LOL